# spirng-data-couchbase writes to the wrong bucket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a simple spring-boot project with `spring-data-couchbase`. In the couchbase I 3 buckets `default-bucket`, `foo-bucket`, and `bar-bucket`.

As well I have a CouchbaseConfig class:

```
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    //Getters for default bucket configuration
    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return hosts;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "default-bucket";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    //Custom configuration
    @Bean
    public Bucket fooBucket() throws Exception {
        return couchbaseCluster().openBucket("foo-bucket");
    }

    @Bean
    public CouchbaseTemplate fooTemplate() throws Exception {
        CouchbaseTemplate template =
                new CouchbaseTemplate(
                        couchbaseClusterInfo(),
                        fooBucket(),
                        mappingCouchbaseConverter(),
                        translationService());
        template.setDefaultConsistency(getDefaultConsistency());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bucket barBucket() throws Exception {
        return couchbaseCluster().openBucket("bar-bucket");
    }

    @Bean
    public CouchbaseTemplate barTemplate() throws Exception {
        CouchbaseTemplate template =
                new CouchbaseTemplate(
                        couchbaseClusterInfo(),
                        barBucket(),
                        mappingCouchbaseConverter(),
                        translationService());
        template.setDefaultConsistency(getDefaultConsistency());
        return template;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(RepositoryOperationsMapping mapping) {
        try {
            mapping.mapEntity(FooDTO.class, fooTemplate());
            mapping.mapEntity(BarDTO.class, barTemplate());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("operation mapping error ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

As well I have `FooDTO` and `BarDTO` `@Documents`:

```
@Document
public class FooDTO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    @Field(value = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Field
    private String field1;

    @Field
    private String field2;

    //getter and setters
}
```

and `BarDTO`:

```
@Document
public class FooDTO {
    @Id
    private String key;

    @Filed
    private List<Baz> bazzes;
    //getter and setters
}

public class Baz {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //getter and setters
}
```

And I have the simple repositories for my DTOs that implements `CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<FooDTO, UUID>` and `ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<BarDTO, String>` respectively.

The problem is that when I save `FooDTO` using my `fooRepository.save()` it gets saved to the `foo-bucket` as expected, but when I'm saving `BarDTO` it gets saved to the `default-bucket` even though I have the mapping `mapping.mapEntity(BarDTO.class, barTemplate());`.

I've tried to change the mapping for the repository like this:

```
mapping.map(BarRepository.class, barTemplate());
```

But nothing is changed and the BarDTO still gets saved to the `default-bucket`.

**UPD**: the problem is that my `BarRepository` is `ReactiveCouchbaseRepository`. So I have to configure it using `AbstractReactiveCouchbaseDataConfiguration`. However, out of the box, I'm not able to have both `AbstractReactiveCouchbaseDataConfiguration` and `AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration` in the same application. It fails with the exception:

```
The bean 'couchbaseEnv', defined in class path resource [], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [] and overriding is disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.2.4.RELEASE or later.

Probably, you are using a spring boot version that uses the Couchbase SDK client version 2.4.6 underneath. This specific version has a bug that you are pointing to.